# Decorator setter is never called

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to write a lazyLoad decorator in typescript
I have come up with the following

```js
function LazyLoad(target: any, propertyKey: PropertyKey, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    const values = new WeakMap<any, { set: undefined | true, value: unknown }>();
    console.log('LazyLoad', target, propertyKey, descriptor);
    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
        set(newValue: any) {
            Object.defineProperty(this, propertyKey, {
                get() {
                    console.log('get');
                    let state = values.get(this);
                    if (state?.set !== true) {
                        state = { set: true, value: descriptor.get?.call(this) }
                        values.set(this, state);
                    }
                    return state.value;
                }
            })
            return this[propertyKey] = newValue;
        }
    })
}
```

And the following code to test it:

```js
class Test {

    private counter = 0;

    @LazyLoad
    get lazyProperty() {
        return this.counter++;
    }

    get nonLazyProperty() {
        return this.counter++;
    }
}
const test = new Test();
console.log(test.lazyProperty);
console.log(test.lazyProperty);

console.log(test.nonLazyProperty);
console.log(test.nonLazyProperty);
```

I expect the output to be

```bash
"LazyLoad"....
set on target
get
0
get
0
1
2
```

but I get the output

```bash
"LazyLoad"....
0
1
2
3
```

It seems my setter is never called, what am I missing?

The code can be tested here: [typescript-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.6.4#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbgLACgAzAVzGABcBLcAAgBlkAvATzpGQBN1y0BzWcgC4ayMMwA0NAA6oQU2KnLMA0rGbCACrPmKVayR1gRgqSlPIhUm7QqUARIybMXUmGgG8CNbzQD0vmiNoSjByAFoOSghkACM4MLBYAA9w4MSaMBAw0EgYWC8fHIhyGgA3ZGhiIxoAXgzYAHcaAHVYZABrAFlkKQAeUQkPGggBYVJDQhDYDhoAHxpyVCrJcsrYMbB2zIawGgBfAD4sPHwfGiK8+GgQXnQAcgYWNk47yR5UfnJJGTlbPUHDMZTOZLDgCt4APIxABWsAo8AmUy0v103D4Am+Nl0qkGnlOZx8I3I6ESDQAahUqsIBm48QT6X4AgAVAAWURoAAMieQFByaJ8IOcKnAZuBgLBpAp6k0QsVROLJKJRWBoMwFiz8viGT5-DRJqhigtKABbCUNCVE9US1ZVGggQhWhboko-HRKeDg7WMmgACQUZolLOQpQlyGA4oggosjtlPDIEo55DZEA5kigNHNNERiU92t1yGkWKUGcoScd0VNGWQldoSYlSGQkZosflCAIuYZFzgVxu90tteddzB+A79KhsPh2dgyLdzG4ycxKKUOMkdK99M+WA8o-XhXAUG711ud0+Q5Ou69utZ7I5nx5qD5AqF0BFgRDqDVVErmdQbRmdebSA43FQsl2YD0tQvAldVaYYTSkVUaGuEB2hoYgpBjIDW0Au1iFQGhjR6EQwBmX9yDw3ZS0FG020gqCfDgEo5R5WoykpIx4E3JMomHej6UoB10GY2AAH54EtABCGo6kWKpaR3Pjhh4Fi6ncYZRgWJZYBWdjhEBJwQVQTiBDE4BhXnHj9gUviaIgcSBAsiA02U2BeMUnw9ms9cyIopTkB5eAaPPPjPLohk9kwdswvpXUADEQmFNVM0tACaLtB1XT+O1dgAhsmxbeMIIvK9kxLF9NMoXh+HwgCuQEe8+VrDVALleN1X8jMJSnGZYhAEMit3HzUBy5MAG1MuxNQAF1WNJCk1mC+lQrOCKCFCgg8sFJkjBKPFPRkShyhY0BSHvViAAYTk9AABR5WHYDhPU+JCmGYGc-i3Nd6SGkaokQEBToUABqIHFqskdIOezIwDu97UXk6KaB+9U-pO0JgdBz1QtCooSh5Q06lJGhtuKY4Nv3S4j24HarleuGlGHLsECp-HyFplh6eYYdydyQ9e1Z+BodhosuZOJme1uAWhbpkXhyAA)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by just returning a `TypedPropertyDescriptor`.

So the final code looks like this:

```js
export default function LazyLoad(_target: any, _propertyKey: PropertyKey, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): TypedPropertyDescriptor<any> {
    //Sanity check
    if (!descriptor.get) {
        throw new Error('Lazy property must have getter');
    }
    if (descriptor.set) {
        throw new Error('Lazy property may not have setter');
    }
    if (descriptor.value != undefined) {
        throw new Error('Lazy property may not have a predefined value');
    }
    const key = Symbol('LazyLoadState');

    return {
        get() {
            const holder = this as { [key: symbol]: { inprogress: boolean, set: boolean, value: unknown } | undefined }
            let state = holder[key];
            if (!state) {
                state = { inprogress: false, set: false, value: undefined }
                holder[key] = state;
            }
            if (state.inprogress) {
                throw new Error('Recursive call to Lazy Property detected!');
            }
            if (!state.set) {
                state.inprogress = true;
                state.value = descriptor.get?.call(this);
                state.inprogress = false;
                state.set = true;
            }

            return state.value;
        }
    }
}
```